# MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

```
 private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog = 'dbcpu'; username = root; password =";
        string query = "select * from dbcpu.student_profile where name'" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string Lname = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Lname"));
                textBoxLname.Text = Lname;

                byte[] imgg = (byte[])(myReader["Pic"]);
                if (imgg == null)
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
                    pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to write something, and not only paste some random piece of code?

Comment: your are missing the = sign `WHERE Name =..` Better yet, use Parameters.Add method

Comment: You really don't want to be using string concatenation on user input to build a query. Google "SQL Injection Attack" for a good explanation of why. It's one of the worst security anti-patterns out there.

Comment: Already fixed. Thanks btw. I just missed some characters to type. :D
I was just sleepy. Lol. :D

Answer (score 0):

If we were to output the contents of the SQL text, it looks like we would get something like this;

```
  ... where name'foo'
```

and that doesn't look like that's part of a valid SQL statement. Maybe you intended something like this?

```
  ... where name = 'foo'
                ^^^
```